# How to check if url exist synchronously in NodeJs ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I would like to know if there is a way to check whether an URL exists synchronously. In fact I am downloading files so I need to make sure these URLs exists before trying to download them. Here is the package I am using to check if these URLs are valid https://github.com/boblauer/url-exists

Comment: Remote requests aren't typically synchronous

Comment: You can't do it asynchronously?

Comment: Just call the url and if it returns a 404, the url doesn't exist... but it will always be async since there are server processes involved and you can't know beforehand how long that will take. Or perhaps the files are on your own server? Then you could create some sort of index containing all available files.

Comment: @epascarello I need it synchro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't.

You can't force an async request to be synchronous.

You have a couple different syntactical approaches (`Promises`, `async/await`, events via Node.js `http`, callbacks, etc), but it's all going to boil down to being async in some way.

The `async/await` pattern will *look* the most synchronous, but it will still be async.

The package you're using specifically uses the callback pattern, so you'll need to adjust your other code to be async. You can mix and match these approaches.

My personal preference is to wrap non-Promise patterns into a Promise pattern, then use `async/await` syntax throughout. Again, this look synchronous, but keep in mind it isn't and deal with it accordingly.

You can wrap callback syntax as a Promise like this:

```
const urlExistsPromise = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    urlExists(url, (err, exists) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(exists));
```

And you can use it like this:

```
urlExistsPromise(url).then(exists => console.log(exists));
```

or as `await` (inside a function labeled `async`):

```
const exists = await urlExistsPromise(url);
```

Comment: Tks @samanine. I will give a try and get back to you. But I think your answer should do the Job.

Comment: Hello. Tks a lo for helping

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`url-exist-sync`](https://github.com/Richienb/url-exist-sync):

```js
const urlExistSync = require("url-exist-sync");

urlExistSync("https://google.com");
//=> true

urlExistSync("https://google.com/404ingURL");
//=> false
```

Comment: the latest build fails for the package, Please check the latest release.

Comment: @SundeepPidugu Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```
const urlExist = require("url-exist");

(async () => {
   urlExist("http://127.0.0.1:5000/").then(exists => 
      mainWindow.loadURL("http://127.0.0.1:5000/"));
  })();
```

This is what worked for me.